# Center a table using html and css

Tags: html, css

I have this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/6UTrz/

I have tried centering the table using a combination of `margin: auto` and `width=70%` as some sites have instructed but the problem is, its not centering properly, especially when I resize the window. It does not stay centered unlike my text.

Any help centering it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire issue, as far as I can tell, is that you're applying the styles to the DIV that contains the table.

If you remove the DIV entirely and apply the styles to the table itself it works just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/aapfp/

```
.vegetableGrid {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:70%;
}

<table class="vegetableGrid">
```

As you can see in that fiddle, I removed the DIV and put the styling directly on the table.

Comment: Thanks for the code it works perfectly, but why exactly wasnt my one working? How come you cant apply the style to the div? Shouldnt it propagate to the table?

Comment: The DIV was being centered on the page, but the table was not being centered within the DIV, nor was it shrinking with the DIV. As the DIV would shrink, table would just overflow from the end and stay left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change img tags and put images in TD style and remove IMG tags. Thus cells will be able to shrink when table needs to shrink. Img tags won't let table shrink so it won't center properly. Let me know if you need additional help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the hard coded width and height of each image in the table. Then you can do something like:

```
   table {
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
```